# Link assembly NASM code to GCC

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, assembly, nasm

I have a trouble with a compiling assembly code (nasm).

On Linux (elf32) it not fails after compilation using g++, but when I tried to build it with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (for Win32) it failed.

My build.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nasm -fwin32 wct.asm
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -m32 -O2 -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffloat-store -ffast-math -fno-rounding-math -fno-signaling-nans -fcx-limited-range -fno-math-errno -funsafe-math-optimizations -fassociative-math -freciprocal-math -ffinite-math-only -fno-signed-zeros -fno-trapping-math -frounding-math -fsingle-precision-constant -fcx-fortran-rules -fno-rtti -mfpmath=387 -mfancy-math-387 -fno-ident -fmerge-all-constants -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -falign-functions=1 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -fno-unroll-loops -fno-math-errno -s main.cpp wct.obj -o wct.exe
strip --strip-unneeded wct.exe
```

There is assembly code:

```
   [bits 32]
   section .text
   global wct

   wct:

    mov esi, [esp+4]
    mov edi, esi
    mov ecx, [esp+8]

    @L:
            lodsw
            sub ax, 04141h

            cmp al,0Fh
            jne @F
            dec al
            jmp @E
            @F:
            cmp al,0Eh
            jne @E
            inc al
            @E:

            mov bx, ax
            shr bx, 8

            cmp bl,0Fh
            jne @@F
            dec bl
            jmp @@E
            @@F:
            cmp bl,0Eh
            jne @@E
            inc bl
            @@E:

            shl al, 4
            add ax, bx
            stosb
    loop @L
    ret
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int wct(char* buff, int N);

#define N 1024*1024

char buff[N];
ifstream in;
ofstream out;
int size;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if ( argc == 1 ) return 0;

    in.open(argv[1], ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

    if ( argc >= 3 )
        out.open(argv[2], ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);

    if( in.is_open())
    {
        while(!in.eof())
        {
            in.read((char *)&buff, sizeof buff);
            size = in.gcount()/2;
            wct((char *)&buff, size);

            if ( out.is_open())
                out.write((char *)&buff, size);
            else
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, because of I am always getting the same error while using build.sh script:

```
/tmp/cc3SD7dA.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x90): undefined reference to `wct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How I can fix that?

Comment: @smac89: In *wct.obj*, the object code that the NASM listing compiled to. I guess there is a mismatch between using the undecorated and decorated symbol. Either NASM mangles it, or GCC. Either way, it needs a calling convention, too.

Comment: @IInspectable, how can I call convention?

Comment: Consult your [compiler's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: @linspectable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Windows the GCC compiler expects a leading underscore in external symbols. So change all `wct` in the asm file to `_wct`.

If you want to test the program in Windows and in Linux you can "globalize" two consecutive labels: `wct` and `_wct`:

```
...
global wct
global _wct
...
wct:
_wct:
...
```

Linux gets the `wct` without underscore and Windows gets it with it.

BTW: The assembly procedure is a C function and has to follow the [CDECL calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). The function can freely change the registers `EAX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` (caller saved). The other registers (`EBX`,`ESI`,`EDI`,`EBP`) have to be returned unchanged. If the function needs to use them, it has to save and restore them (callee saved):

```
wct:
_wct:

 push esi                ; sp+= 4
 push edi                ; sp+= 4
 push ebx                ; sp+= 4
                        ; ======
                        ; sp+= 12
 mov esi, [esp+16]
 mov edi, esi
 mov ecx, [esp+20]

 ...

 pop ebx
 pop edi
 pop esi
 ret
```